# How to change citation format?

Tags: latex, formatting, bibtex, citations

I'm using Harvard citations in a paper.
I use the following options:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Comparison}
```

When I use \cite and \citep I get the following at the end of the pdf:

> S.Shekhar and S.Chawla. Spatial databases: a tour. PrenticeHall, 2003.

Actually I'd like to get the usual Harvard format:

> S.Shekhar and S.Chawla. (2003) Spatial databases: a tour. PrenticeHall

How can I fix the format?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Look up the `\setcitestyle` command to get round brackets:

```
\setcitestyle{round}
```

But in general, you need to get an appropriate style file instead of `plainnat`. The `makebst` program will generate you a BST style file for almost any specification.